# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)

Tags: python, pycharm

The error is at `script, first, second, third = argv`. I would like to understand why I am getting the error and how to fix it.

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv
print("The script is called: ", script)
print("The first variable is: ", first)
print("The second variable is: ", second)
print("The third variable is: ", third)
```

Comment: you just ran the script without any arguments, for your code to work you should pass at least 3 arguments like `python script.py arg1 arg2 arg3`

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm getting ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1), is it because I'm running it in pycharm rather than using cmd?

Comment: You'll need to tell pycharm to pass in arguments / parameters, otherwise it will simply execute the script without any arguments.

Comment: I had the same error running the examples from "Learn Python 3 the Hard Way: A Very Simple Introduction to the Terrifyingly Beautiful World of Computers and Code", When i found your question, i said, "i known that code".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argv` variable contains command line arguments. In your code you expected 4 arguments, but got only 1 (first argument always script name). You could configure arguments in `pycharm`. Go to `Run` -> `Edit Configurations`. Then create a new python configuration. And there you could specify `Script parameters` field. Or you could run your script from command line as mentioned by dnit13.

Answer (score 5):

Run it from the shell like this:

```
python script.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: This happens when you do not put enough arguments on the command when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

You could run it like this: python script.py first, second, third

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running the following command:

```
python script.py
```

You are writing a program which is aksing for 4 inputs and you are giving onle one. That's why you are receiving an error. You can use the below command:

```
python script.py Hello How Are
```