# Is there any way to solve the argv unpacking problem

Tags: python-3.7

Not enough values to unpack argv variable

```
from sys import argv

script, user_name = argv
prompt = '>'

print("Hi %s I am the %s script." % (user_name, script))

print("I would like to ask you a few questions.")

print("Do you like me %s?" % user_name)
likes = input(prompt)

print("Where do you live %s?" % user_name)
lives = input(prompt)

print("What kind of computer do you have?")
computer = input(prompt)

print("""
Alright, so you said %r about liking me.
You live in %r. Not sure where that is.
And you have a %r computer. Nice.
""" % (likes, lives, computer))
```

ERROR:

line 3, in 
    script, user_name = argv
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: This question seems to be identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55211283/valueerror-not-enough-values-to-unpack-expected-2-got-1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093126/valueerror-not-enough-values-to-unpack-expected-4-got-1)